# php conditional mixed insert and update of mysql from csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, insert-update

I have a set of csv files to add to or update several tables. The csv data is a mix of old (possibly changed) records and new.

That means during the import I have to check whether that record exists - updating if it does and inserting if not. To add to the fun the unique columns are mostly guid format and are not the first in the listing.

Ultimately I want to use an array of file names and the column used in each for searching and iterate through that to automate the import.

So I have been adapting ideas found in my searches here and have succeeded in getting the insert to work but I just cannot construct an effective update instruction.

In the code I am echoing the mysql so I can see (and check via phpAdmin) what is going on. I just cannot get any content out of $settin

```
$con= mysql_connect("my_connection_details");
mysql_select_db('issuetest');
function csv_file_to_mysql_table($source_file, $target_table, $fieln, $max_line_length=0) {
    if (($handle = fopen("$source_file", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",");
        $key = array_search($fieln, $columns);
        foreach ($columns as &$column) {
            $column = str_replace(".","",$column);
        }
        $insert_prefix = "INSERT INTO $target_table (".join(",",$columns).")\nVALUES";
        $update_prefix = "UPDATE $target_table SET ";
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            while (count($data)<count($columns)){
            array_push($data, NULL);
            }
            $sql="SELECT $fieln FROM  $target_table WHERE $fieln='$data[$key]'";
            if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))=='0'){
                $query = "$insert_prefix (".join(",",quote_all_array($data)).");";
                }else{
                $settin='';
                $i='0';
                reset($data);
                reset ($columns);
                while (count($data)<count($columns)){
                    if($i=='0'){$settin.="$columns[$i] ='".$data[$i]."'";   
                        }else{$settin.=",$columns[$i]='".$data[$i]."'"; 
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
                $query = "$update_prefix $settin  WHERE $fieln='$data[$key]';";
            }
            echo $query;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

function quote_all_array($values) {
    foreach ($values as $key=>$value)
    if (is_array($value))
    $values[$key] = quote_all_array($value);
    else
    $values[$key] = quote_all($value);
    return $values;
}

function quote_all($value) {
    if (is_null($value))
    return "NULL";
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    return $value;
} 
//$fiel is name of field to check 
//fileN ia name of csv file
//$tabname is table to insert into
$fiel='my_field';
$tabname='my_table';
$fileN='my_csv';

$fg=csv_file_to_mysql_table($fileN,$tabname,$fiel);
```

Comment: Have you considered `insert...on duplicate key update`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this

```
while(count($data)<count($columns))
```

would ever change
Maybe you mean something like

```
$min= min(count($data),count($columns));
    while($i<$min)
```

Comment: Thanks for that - It was a woods and trees thing and a bit of mental stupor thanks to working in the early hours- actually it just needed while($i<count($columns))